# Abrir app Android com ligação

Tags: android, intent

Eu quero saber,como o aplicativo [Cerberus](https://www.cerberusapp.com/), para Android, consegue abrir sua aplicação quando ligamos para um determinado número?

Para quem não conhece Cerberus, é um aplicativo anti-furto, então ele esconde o seu ícone para que as pessoas não percebam que ele está instalado.

Se voce ligar  para o número padrão ou o que voce cadastrou, o aplicativo abre!

Como podemos ver aqui:

> '...ou pode abrir o Cerberus no telefone discando o "código de discagem", como se fosse um número de telefone. Se você não alterou, o código de discagem padrão é 23723787.'

O app sobrescreve alguma precedencia do SO?

Como consigo fazer isso?

Answer (score 3):

Você deve criar um *BroadcastReceiver* que intercepte a ação `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`

```
public class OutgoingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String numero = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

        String msg = "Acabou de marcar o seguinte numero: " + numero;
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Terá de registar o BroadcastReceiver no AndroidManifest:

```
......
<receiver android:name="OutgoingCallReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
 ......
```

Não esquecer de incluir a seguinte permissão:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
```